# I want to make the callback wait for the response before executing the next lines of code

Tags: javascript

I want to make the callback wait for the response before executing the next lines of code. 
I did try to make the callback `async` then `await` for the response, but that didn't work.

```
async signup(parent, args, ctx, info) {

    const email = args.email;
    let res;
    verifier.verify(email, function(err, response) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else {
        res = response.success;
        console.log('before', res); // true or false
      }
    });
    console.log('after', res); // undefined
}
```

Comment: you need to use ```await``` and store that into a variable. something like : async function signup() {
    var response = await fetch('https://your.api.call');
    return response;
};signup().then(result => console.log(result));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function signup (parent, args) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    verifier.verify(args.email, function(err, response) {
      if (err) { 
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(response.success);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much that did work i did `await` the promise and i did assign it into a variable and that did work

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and execute it after getting response

```
async signup(parent, args, ctx, info) {

const email = args.email;
let res;
verifier.verify(email, function(err, response) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    res = response.success;
    console.log('before', res); // true or false
    nextfun(res)
  }
});
}


function nextfun(res) {
 console.log(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 async signup(parent, args, ctx, info) {

    let res = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      verifier.verify(args.email, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(response.success);
        }
      });
    });

    console.log('after', res); // response.success

}
```